# Delphi & Finalbuilder EMBA Edition

Tags: delphi, finalbuilder

Can I execute a FinalBuilder build file  (*.fbz7) from another FinalBuilder script file ?

Why:

Script #1 (my Master script)  should contain a script looping script #2  for several times or based on a given variable I can selected between script #3 or script #4  to be executed

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Include Project](http://help.finalbuilder.com/Index.htm?includeproject.htm) action, which allows you to specify the script. You can actually run old version scripts, so if you have version 6 and 7, both can run a script created in version 6.

I realise that you specify the Embarcadero edition. The full version certainly has this option - if the limited edition doesn't, then upgrading will obviously make it easy.

Comment: any other solution avaiable to branch the execution of scripts

Comment: @Franz The other option, again not sure if it is in the Emb version, is the Action List, which is effectively a sub-routine.